# How can I say "it was tried"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In my thesis I want to write the following:

> Second, by using the [...] and [...] it was tried to find an appropriate model.

I am not sure about the "it was tried". Can I use it? What would be better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think "it was tried" followed by an infinitive is acceptable English.  If you have to use the passive voice for stylistic reasons, you could instead say "an attempt was made":

> Second, by using the [...] and [...], ***an attempt was made*** to find an appropriate model.

Answer (score 7):

Although snailboat's answer is completely valid for the case where the passive voice is *required*, I would like to add that the active voice usually sounds much better in most scenarios:

> Second, by using the [...] and [...], **we tried** to find an appropriate model.